# XAMPP is not working

Tags: xampp

I just installed this last night and it is  properly working but today it is not working. I can't access my localhost and phpmyadmin and getting server not found page.

```
Apache 2.2.11
MySQL 5.1.33 (Community Server)
PHP 5.2.9 + PEAR (Support for PHP 4 has been discontinued)
XAMPP Control Version 2.5 from www.nat32.com
phpMyAdmin 3.1.3.1
```

Comment: Please add more useful information. Have you read the [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide?

Comment: If page it's not found (404) then it's an Apache problem most likely (altough could be php if you have an MVC FWK). Post the vhost or at least the configuration and path and OS as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please install `xampp` in other drive(`D:\` or `E:\`). Don't install in drive where your Operating System is installed. this will solve your problem if not than just right click on **xampp-control.exe** in `xampp` folder and click *Run as administrator*, Install Both service `apache` and `mysql`. Restart PC. Your problem will be solved.