# XAMPP not working in Windows 10

Tags: apache, windows-10-desktop

02:42:04  [Apache]  Problem detected!
02:42:04  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with `pid` 4!
02:42:04  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
02:42:04  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
02:42:04  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
02:42:04  [Apache]  `XAMPP` Apache is already running on port 443

and i stop World Wide Web Publishing Service but it still not working

Comment: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317372/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! 12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558410/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4-12)

Comment: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42453650/4144338) ! This answer might be helpful to you.

Comment: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42453650/4144338) ! This might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Open DOS as administrator and tipe the following line:

> NET stop HTTP

It will stops all windows services that use the port 80 and you will good to go starting XAMPP.